# can Abaqus getByBoundingBox or findAt() be used for odb?

Tags: scripting, abaqus

I like to find a node or an element based on coordinates in odb in order to plot the data at that node or element. I am wondering if it is possible to use getByBoundingBox() or findAt() in odb?  If so, how does it work in odb to find the node and element based on coordinates? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can use the `getByBoundingSphere(...)` on any `MeshNodeArray` object.
As example, a `MeshNodeArray` can be accessed through the root structure: odb/rootAssembly/instance/elements